# chart.js line for only part of the labels

Tags: charts, chart.js

I'm making a chart via chart.js with 6 labels; 6 bars are displayed. I also have to draw a line, but only between labels/bars 3 and 4 .. so for labels 1,2,5 and 6 no line is displayed. How is this done ?

Comment: Please be more clear on how you want to draw a line because you can draw lines in lots of ways between them

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: just fill the data with null for the labels/bars where you don't want a line to be drawn.

Comment: Can you add more details of your solution? also, please, remember accept your own answer.